# How do I breed an Iron dragon?

Tags: dragonvale

In my other question, I'd talked about breeding the Peridot dragon and going to try to use the Fog and Iron combination. Now I just need the breeding combination for the Iron dragon. Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iron's a pretty easy one - any combo of dragons that contain both Metal and Earth has a chance of producing Iron.

However, probably the best combo is also the easiest - an Earth dragon with a Metal dragon.  This has a 50/50 chance of producing an Iron dragon, and the failed combos aren't worse than average.